# Can't work custom tools on Zim Desktop

Tags: python, custom-tools

I can't figure how to work with custom tools in Zim Desktop

I'm on windows10
Zim Desktop portable edition 0.65
Python 2.7 or 3.6, I've tried both

Every time I get this messagge:

```
%1 non è un programma win32 valido
```

thats for: this isn't a win32 valid program

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Win10. I have the following script in folder `c:/scratch` and it's called `temp.py`. As you can see, it's sole job is to attempt to open the URL that's passed to it via its single command line parameter.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import webbrowser
    from sys import argv
    webbrowser.open(argv[1])
```

As instructed in the Zim docs, I open the `Tools|Custom Tools` dialogue box, and click on the 'plus' icon, then fill in the details as shown here.

[image: dialogue]

Now I can go back to a Zim page with a URL like this one,

[image: Zim page]

highlight the URL, then choose `Launch highlighted URL` from the `Tools` menu and presto, that page loads in my browser.

That's the basic idea anyway.